# remove blank space below section before pdf in latex

Tags: pdfpages, include

I have a little problem with Latex. I wanna add some pdfs to my master thesis and I have a problem that I couldn't find the answer so far.

After the `\section`, the rest of the page stays empty and the pdf is in the other page. How can I delete this and have the pdf right below the section ?

Thank you !

Here is part of my code:

```
\chapter{Annexes}

    Ce chapitre regroupe les protocoles, les résultats bruts, ainsi que le script R utilisés dans ce travail qui n'ont pas pu être affiché dans les parties précédentes par manque de place et par esthétique.

\section{Protocoles}

    \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1-},pagecommand=\subsection{Capacité d'échange cationique}]{protocole/CEC.pdf}
    \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1-},pagecommand=\subsection{Analyse carbone, hydrogène et azote}]{protocole/CHN.pdf}
    \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1-},pagecommand=\subsection{pH}]{protocole/pH.pdf}
    \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1-},pagecommand=\subsection{Phosphore biodisponible}]{protocole/phosphore.pdf}

\section {Tableaux des résultats}

    \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1-},pagecommand=\subsection{Semences employées}]{tableau/semencesUFA.pdf}
    \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1-},pagecommand=\subsection{Développement des espèces}]{tableau/species_shoot.pdf}
    \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1-},pagecommand=\subsection{Résultats généraux de la végétation}]{tableau/vegetation_general.pdf}          
    \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1-},pagecommand=\subsection{Caractéristique des sols}]{tableau/results_soil.pdf}   
    \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1-},pagecommand=\subsection{\textit{P. lanceolata}, génotype basse altitude}]{tableau/plantago_low_species.pdf}
    \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1-},pagecommand=\subsection{\textit{P. lanceolata}, génotype haute altitude}]{tableau/plantago_high_species.pdf}

\section {Script R}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! You should complete you code snippet to a minimal document.  The reason that is moved to the next page is that it is too large for the remaining space.  Would it be acceptable to add a `\clearpage` before each `\section` ?

Comment: \includepdf forces a new page. You can either add the \section command to the pagecommand key, or you will have to use \includegraphics instead of \includepdf for the first page.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you! I use the Andrew Swann method, I took out the first `\subsection`, I use `\includegraphics` for the first page, then I use `\includepdf` for the rest! So my document looks like this now:

```
\section{Protocoles}

\subsection{Capacité d'échange cationique}

    \includegraphics[scale=0.8,page=1]{protocole/CEC.pdf}
    \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={2-}]{protocole/CEC.pdf}
    \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1-},pagecommand=\subsection{Analyse carbone, hydrogène et azote}]{protocole/CHN.pdf}
```

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).